# How to get multiple AngularJS calendar directive to work independently?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have the following calendar control which I display twice on a page.

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/pe4sfex6/14/

```
<div>
    <calendar selected="day"></calendar>
    <div>Selected date: <b>{{day.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}}</b></div>
</div>

<div>
    <calendar selected="day"></calendar>
    <div>Selected date: <b>{{day.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}}</b></>
</div>
```

When I click the date on one calendar, the other one changes as well, e.g. they both have the same scope. I want them to have separate scopes.

So I can comment out the kind of scope:

```
scope: {
    //selected: "="
},
```

and give the controls separate variables:

```
<div>
    <calendar selected="day1"></calendar>
    <div>Selected date: <b>{{day1.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}}</b></div>
</div>

<div>
    <calendar selected="day2"></calendar>
    <div>Selected date: <b>{{day2.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}}</b></>
</div>
```

Then I can set the date on each separately, BUT, then the dates don't appear anymore.

**How can I both (1) have the controls work independently, and (2) enable each directive to change its own variable?**

Comment: Changing to `day1` and `day2` works: http://jsfiddle.net/pe4sfex6/16/. Am I right?

Comment: Strange, yes, now it works. I must have had something else changed when I tried it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to day1 and day2 works: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pe4sfex6/16):

```
<div>
    <calendar selected="day1"></calendar>
    <span>Selected date: <b>{{day1.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}}</b></span>
</div>

<div>
    <calendar selected="day2"></calendar>
    <span>Selected date: <b>{{day2.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}}</b></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the last bit into your jsfiddle, but don't change the scope definition of your directive, then your code seems to work like you want it to.

The directive is 'instantiated' twice, in one `$scope.selected == day1`, in the other `$scope.selected == day2`.